# Spring-data-mongo: Disable automatically mapping the "id" field to "_id" in Mongo unless annotated

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Spring-data for mongodb treats fields named "id" special: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#d0e1508, in that it tries to map a field named id to the _id field in MongoDB. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I'd like the mongodb ObjectId only mapped to fields with the explicit `@Id` annotation. Currently I have fields named id in mongodb, and this is not something I can change, and I'm finding it to be near impossible to get spring-data to map the correct id value back into the pojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Spring Data MongoDB (1.2.0.RELEASE) would reject a class with multiple id properties (annotated or default ones). If you think we should get more lenient on this (ignoring all default properties if a property is explicitly annotated with `@Id`) feel free to open a ticket in our [JIRA](http://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO). The current behavior is implemented to eagerly discover potential misconfiguration that might have occurred when moving from default mappings to explicitly annotated.

Comment: The Problem is that a field named id is not necessarily _id and it appears there is no way to get spring to see otherwise. I'll oPen the Jira but it appears my only option in the short term is morphia.

Comment: my other option is to use a custom converter, but at that point I've done the object mapping myself, and I'm not sure what value spring data has provided.

Comment: Hi Oliver, if the DEFAULT_ID_NAMES array was changed to only contain _id (here: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/QueryMapper.java), would that produce the desired behavior for me?

Comment: Hey was there ever a solution or ticket for this? I'm facing the exact same problem 10 years later where I have a bunch of "id" fields that I don't want Spring to map to "_id" unless it has @Id on it, and I don't want to put `@Field("id")` all over the code either just for Spring.

Comment: Ok, there is a ticket for it [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3351) opened in 2020