# spring data mongodb "id" field mapping

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a document with an array field with

```
"chapters": [
  { "id" : "14031871223912313", ...}
  ...
  ]
```

I would like to query return the id's with Spring Data's MongoTemplate using the following:

```
class Chapter {
 private String id;
 public String getId() {
        return id;
    } 
}
```

This way the id is not populated. I have tried using the different mapping options with @Field described here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field

What am I doing wrong? I know I can always to back to mongo java driver, but I thought this should work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: *"A field annotated with @Id (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id' field."*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a solution. It is populated via:

```
  @Field("id")
  private String chaperId
```

Comment: Is there a way to enable this globally so I don't have to specify this annotation for all my embedded documents?

Comment: Ok just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14846894/6854489) asking the same thing but it's 10 years old with no solution lol. (At least an official Spring developer had written their answer on that question)

Answer (score 3):

In MongoDB id's are `_id`, and every document in mongo has an `_id`. From the document you linked to, Spring will map `@Field String id` to mongo's `_id` field. You probably want to use a `@Field('id') String id` field mapping to indicate that the field you want is `id` not `_id`.

Comment: @tantalum yes, even when using `@Field("id") String id` is not getting populated

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg cannot use `@Id` since it is not the id of the document