# @Field annotation not working for ID field in Spring Data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a nested document which contains a field called `id`.  Spring Data is automatically converting it to `_id`, but this is unnecessary since it's a nested document.  I saw that someone asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637813/spring-data-mongodb-id-field-mapping), and so I added the annotation `@Field("id")`.  However, it does not appear to be working, and the field is still saved as `_id`.  What's especially bizarre is that I added the annotation to another field on the class, and the alternate field name is used:

```
@Field("x")
private String id;
@Field("y")
private String type;
```

After making this change, the document in Mongo appeared as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "abc",
    "y" : "def"
}
```

Another weird thing is that I have a query on `field.id` that consistently returns results, even though the documents are actually stored as `field._id`.  The same query does not return results from the shell.

To save myself the frustration of trying to debug the problem further, would there be any negative effects of just leaving the field as `_id`?

Comment: which version of spring-data-mongodb are you using? The doc explains the `id` mapping [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field). Please provide a bit more context on the entity saved (full declaration + resulting bson representation)

Comment: I am using version 1.6.1.RELEASE.  I saw that documentation, which is why I expected the @Field mapping from my original post to work, but it only appears to work for the `type` field and not the `id` field.  The rest of the class doesn't really contain much more than what I posted, aside from the expected constructors/getters/setters (I don't think I can post it here due to the comment character limit).  And by "resulting BSON representation", do you mean what gets stored in Mongo?  That is in my original post as well.

Comment: The only complicating factor I can think of is that it's a nested object, rather than its own root-level document.

Comment: the changes have not been back ported to 1.6 (Evans) and are available since the 1.7 (Fowler) release. See [DATAMONGO-1050](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1050).